# Stick Image Right Side of page

Tags: html, css

I want to insert [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak5k9.png) to this [web-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCFr7.png), a sticker, but even I tried the header of page, between the navbar and the image-slider gain a blanket space.

this is my code:

```
<style>
.fix{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:80%;
}
</style>

<img src="http://hunes.suryamkt.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/login-btn.png" class="fix"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a width and height to the image. Also, instead of an image tag, you should use it as a background image for an inline element and then position it.

Try this:

```
.fix{ 
  position:fixed; 
  bottom:0px; 
  left:80%;
  height: 50px; //Set it to the desired size
  width: 50px; //Set it to the desired size
  z-index: 9999999; //Incase you can't see the image.
}
```

Comment: thx, you are the light my code stayed like this:
 .fix{ 
  position:fixed; 
  bottom:0px;
  top:60%;
  right:0%;
  height: 137px; 
  width: 39px; 
  z-index: 9999999; 
}

Answer (score 0):

What you've got is fine, but you need to add a `z-index` so it will be above your navbar. The value I found that works is `z-index: 100000;`